A kids novel with a character named Cassandra and a colourful cover
I'm looking for a kids novel with a character named Cassandra.
The cover was colourful. The girl may have had orange hair. She had an uncle who was a little magical; he invented knitting needles to sew up the ozone layer. He lost the sparkle in his eye and put it into a jewelry box. It sounds crazy, I know. There was an old man who had never seen the sea. I borrowed it from the local library and can't find it anymore. Read it about 10 years ago.

When cross-posting, it's always a good idea to tell us where; https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/1dioddc/kids_novel_character_named_cassandra/ - Then we can discount things you've discounted elsewhere

This question could be improved by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.
